# How to refer a task success status of one dag to another dag

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a scenario like below:

dag A :
task 1,
task 2

Dag B :
Task 3,
Task 4

Now i want to trigger/ run the task 3 (dag B) only after the success of task 1(dag A). Both dags scheduled on the same day but different time.
For example:Dag A runs on 14 July 8 AM,.
Dag B runs on 14 July 2 PM

Is that doable? How?

Please help

Thanks

Comment: do you need to run Task3 once task1 finished or when DagB starts do you want task3 to work ?

Comment: When dag B starts then only task 3 should run

Answer (score 0):

In DagB you should create a BranchPythonOperator that returns "task3" if the appropriate conditions occurred.

in this code example, I return "task3" only if "DagA" finished state=success on the same day.

```
def check_success_dag_a(**context):
    ti: TaskInstance = context['ti']
    dag_run: DagRun = context['dag_run']
    date: datetime = ti.execution_date
    ts = timezone.make_aware(datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day, 0, 0, 0))
    dag_a = dag_run.find(
        dag_id='DagA',
        state="success",
        execution_start_date=ts,
        execution_end_date=ti.execution_date)
    if dag_a:
        return "task3"

check_success = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id="check_success_dag_a",
    python_callable=check_success_dag_a,
)


def run(**context):
    ti = context['ti']
    print(ti.task_id)


task3 = PythonOperator(
    task_id="task3",
    python_callable=run,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS
)

task4 = PythonOperator(
    task_id="task4",
    python_callable=run,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS
)

(check_success >> [task3] >> task4)
```